# Get the contents of a message someone replied to

Tags: discord.py

I'm trying to get the contents of a message someone replied to, but I'm not sure how to do it. I've been going through discord.py documentation and coming out empty handed. How should I get my bot to fetch the contents of this message (circled in red), and is it even possible?

[image: A message someone has replied to]]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Always see [the Discord Models](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord-models). See all the attributes of the model ([`discord.Message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Message) in your case). The attribute you're looking for is [`Message.reference`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Message.reference). To get its contents, after getting the reference message using `reference = <reply_message>.reference`, get its content using `content = reference.content`. It'd be `content = <reply_message>.reference.content`.

Answer (score 0):

1rst message: the one in red, which you are looking for

2nd message: the one that responds to the 1rst one

- First, you get the 2nd message. This is a `discord.Message`, and
  has the `reference` attribute.
- Then, from the `reference`, which is a
  `discord.MessageReference`, you get the `message_id` (and the
  `channel_id` if you don't already have it)
- Finally, you get the 1rst message by searching the `message_id`
  in the channel (that you get with `channel_id` if you don't
  already have it)